# run configuration for scala in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, scala

hi i have to run a scala programme. i got the error Main class not found.then i open preferences and in scala application. main class column no main class specified . can u please tell me what must i have to fill in that colummn to run my programme.please help me.thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [faces error in running the scala project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406427/faces-error-in-running-the-scala-project)

Comment: In fact, this question was created anew by @raghav. Since it is better formated there, I choose this one to close.

Comment: You should have just edited this question instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 3):

Can you provide any extra information?

I've just created a Scala project, right click new Scala Project. Keep all defaults. Created the following object

```
object HelloWorld {

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { println("Hello World!") }

 }
```

Right click on the file in the Package Explorer and select `"Run As"` -> `"Scala Application"`

I'm using Eclipse
Version: 3.5.2
Build id: M20100211-1343

Plugin version 1.0.0.201011220809

Check you are in the Scala Perspective and not Java.

Comment: this does work until you create a second file that is not the main class and try to run the project with that file in focus.