# faces error in running the scala project

Tags: java, eclipse, scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [run configuration for scala in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405767/run-configuration-for-scala-in-eclipse)

please help me this time. I am running a scala project and got an error:

> could not find main class in: main.scala.controls.MyServer.

I'm running main.scala and there is a object of name MyServer. Is it necessary to create a class for it. Please respond

Comment: What are you filling in "main class" field of the run configuration?

Comment: You need to provide more information. What IDE are you using? What is the version? What is the version of the Scala plugin you are using? What does the code look like -- at least the code to MyServer? Please edit _this_ question, and provide more information.

Comment: Closing this one rather than the other because the other has an answer with upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm running main.scala and there is a object of name MyServer. Is it necessary to create a class for it.

No, you don't need to create a class. All you need is an object with a `main` method:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { println("hello") }
```

Anyway, provide more info: code, how you try to run it, building system, IDE, etc.